# Scala filling null with an array in a dataframe throws data type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe of parent product embeddings and a dataframe of child product embeddings. Each row is a product and its 64-d embedding. Each row has 65 columns, the first column is product ID, the rest of columns are the elements of the 64-d embeddings.
I also have default embeddings for parent and child with the same schema as above.

Embedding are assembled and normalized as below:

```
def normalizeEmbeddings(df: DataFrame, embeddingSize: Int = 64): DataFrame = {
    val denseVectorDf = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols((0.until(embeddingSize)).toArray.map(_.toString))
      .setOutputCol("vector")
      .transform(df)
    new Normalizer().setInputCol("vector").setOutputCol("normalized_vector").setP(2).transform(denseVectorDf)
  }

val normalizedParentEmbeddingDf = normalizeEmbeddings(parentEmbeddingDf)
val normalizedChildEmbeddingDf = normalizeEmbeddings(childEmbeddingDf)
val normalizedDefaultParentEmbeddingDf = normalizeEmbeddings(defaultParentEmbedding)  # one row
val normalizedDefaultChildEmbeddingDf = normalizeEmbeddings(defaultChildEmbedding)  # one row
```

Parent embeddings and child embeddings are then joined with sample data. The logic is that any parent products or child products have no embeddings, they will use default embeddings.

```
val joinedDf = sampleDf
  .join(
    normalizedParentEmbedding.select(col("parent_product"), col("normalized_vector").as("parent_vector")),
    Seq("parent_product"),
    "left"
  )
  .join(
    normalizedChildEmbeddingDf.select(col("child_product"), col("normalized_vector").alias("child_vector")),
    Seq("child_product"),
    "left"
  )
  .withColumn("parent_vector", when(col("parent_vector").isNull, normalizedDefaultParentEmbeddingDf.select("parent_vector").head()(0)).otherwise(col("parent_vector")))  # ERROR!
  .withColumn("child_vector", when(col("child_vector").isNull, normalizedDefaultChildEmbeddingDf.select("child_vector").head()(0)).otherwise(col("child_vector")))
```

However, I get an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (`parent_vector` IS NULL) THEN 'default' ELSE `parent_vector` END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;
```

It seems the line that fills in the default embedding is not correct.
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your default value in `lit(...)`.

Otherwise the then expression is a `String` whereas the else expression is a `Column`. Using `lit(...)` transforms a litteral value into a `Column` of that value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But adding lit(), I get an error "Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector [0.15935861532906645,0.15715807686945962, ... ]"

Comment: What's the type of your then value? It looked like a String and now it's a vector? Or did you put the `lit` in a wrong place maybe?